# Change file to read-only mode in Python

Tags: python, file-io

I am writing a data processing code, in which I create a new file, write processed data in to this file and close. But the file has to be closed in read-only mode, so that it would not be accidentally modified. Can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For this you use [`os.chmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod)

```
import os
from stat import S_IREAD, S_IRGRP, S_IROTH

filename = "path/to/file"
os.chmod(filename, S_IREAD|S_IRGRP|S_IROTH)
```

Note that this assumes you have appropriate permissions, and that you want more than just the owner to be able to read the file. Remove `S_IROTH` and `S_IRGRP` as appropriate if that's not the case.

**UPDATE**

If you need to make the file writable again, simply call `os.chmod` as so:

```
from stat import S_IWUSR # Need to add this import to the ones above

os.chmod(filename, S_IWUSR|S_IREAD) # This makes the file read/write for the owner
```

Simply call this before you open the file for writing, then call the first form to make it read-only again after you're done.

Comment: And how do I change it to write when I run the program. I want to change it to write when the program runs and when it exits it should be changed to read-only mode.

Comment: Ah, you didn't specify that in the original question. I'll update

Comment: Does not work on Windows. Even if this article says it should
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod

Answer (score 6):

This solution preserves previous permission of the file, acting like command `chmod -w FILE`

```py
import os
import stat

filename = "path/to/file"
mode = os.stat(filename).st_mode
ro_mask = 0o777 ^ (stat.S_IWRITE | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IWOTH)
os.chmod(filename, mode & ro_mask)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `pathlib.Path`, for modern python3, use `path.chmod(mode: int)`

The octal mode could be specified like `0o444` (read only). [See this for more chmod mode options](https://linuxize.com/post/chmod-command-in-linux/).

Note, if it is to apply to the symlink itself, see `path.lchmod`.
For `path.chmod`, after 3.10, there's now a `follow_symlinks = True` parameter as well.

On windows, this may not be sufficient for anything but twiddling the read-only flag. See other SO posts [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130551/6069586).

Answer (score -2):

For Windows OS maybe to try something like this:

```
import os

filename = open("file_name.txt", "w")
filename.write("my text")
filename.close()
os.system("attrib +r file_name.txt")
```

Comment: Not recommended because it is not operating system independent, and because it fails if file_name has a space in it.

Comment: This seems to be the same as @dgsleeps answer that was posted 3 years earlier

Answer (score -3):

I guess you could use os module after writing on your file to change the file permissions like this:

```
import os
filename=open("file_name","w")
filename.write("my text")
filename.close()
os.system("chmod 444 file_name")
```

Comment: calling chmod via `os.system` isn't portable, it won't work on windows. Better to use the `os.chmod` method directly.