How to set a file permission to prevent deletion in Python?
I'm working on a Python project and I need to prevent a file from being deleted. If it's not possible to make the file undeletable, I would like to at least make it read-only and unchangeable.
I've tried using os module but I'm unsure how to achieve this. Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to set file permissions in Python to prevent deletion or make the file read-only?

Have you tried setting the file to readonly with os.chmod? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492685/change-file-to-read-only-mode-in-python

This question is similar to: Change file to read-only mode in Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, you can use os.chmod() to change the permissions of a file.
os.chmod(file_path, 0o555)

This makes a file unwritable by every user on the system.
To adjust this behaviour, just replace the 555 numeric code with something else. You can use an online chmod calculator to generate a chmod permission code.
An example code that makes a file readable and writable by every user:
os.chmod(file_path, 0o777)

I hope this solved your problem!
